# Multiple definition error in c++

Tags: c++

Hi when i try to run c++ code I am getting the following error

`mainwindow.h`

```
class MainWindow
{


  public:
     MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
     method();
};
```

and

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include mainwindow.h
MainWindow::MainWindow(){
   //some code here

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
  //some code here

}
MainWindow::method(){
  //some code here

}
```

when i compile this from eclipse cdt i got the error saying multiple defintion of `MainWindow::method()` .
Is this the correct way or iam doing anything wrong.
Can any one please help me what to do?

Comment: Need to post more code- this isn't the error.

Comment: Where is the return type of `method()` that you have declared inside the class in your header file ?

Comment: Does the error occur when compiling mainwindow.cpp or some other cpp file using the header?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you include your header in several cpp, and it has no guard preventing from multiple includes, like `pragma once` or

```
#ifndef MainWindow_h 
#define MainWindow_h
class MainWindow
{


  public:
     MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
     method();
};
#endif
```

Comment: No, that would lead to a different error (redefinition of `class MainWindow`).